# Key error '0' when multiplying by a length 1 pandas series

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

For reasons, I'm currently running a for loop in which `A x N` arrays (actually `xarray` data arrays, but the problem persists with basic `numpy` arrays as in the MRE below) are multiplied by `N x 1` pandas series (to form `A x 1` arrays), for various `N`s.

This works fine as long as `N>1`. But as soon as `N=1` (aka the entire array is just multiplied by the same value), an odd `KeyError` appears (see below).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Size 2x1 series, multiplication works fine
a = np.reshape(np.array(np.random.rand(10,2)),(10,-1))
b = [pd.Series(data=[1.0,1.0],index=[1,2])]
a*b


# Size 1x1 series, multiplication fails 
a = np.reshape(np.array(np.random.rand(10,1)),(10,-1))
b = [pd.Series(data=[1.0],index=[1])]
a*b
```

```
# With following error message
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-112-d29b22165258> in <module>
      1 a = np.reshape(np.array(np.random.rand(10,1)),(10,-1))
      2 b = [pd.Series(data=[1.0],index=[1])]
----> 3 a*b

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/climate1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    869         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    870         try:
--> 871             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    872 
    873             if not is_scalar(result):

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/climate1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4402         k = self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")
   4403         try:
-> 4404             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4405         except KeyError as e1:
   4406             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

I've found a workaround that replaces explicitly the series with floats:

```
# This works fine
a = np.reshape(np.array(np.random.rand(10,1)),(10,-1))
b = [pd.Series(data=[1.0],index=[1])]
a*[float(k) for k in b]
```

But I would love any help in understanding where this error message comes from; since I suspect that I'm misunderstanding something more fundamental about `pandas`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This works for me on pandas version 1.1, numpy version 1.19. What version are you using?

Comment: ah, interesting - I'm on pandas 1.0.3 and numpy 1.18.1, so it might've gotten fixed then and I just haven't updated in a while!

Comment: Code works in Google Colab too. [Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bWIxri1GJyT8iekW-HpRVbgZnYaq1wF7?usp=sharing).

Comment: Yeah; looks like it's just a version issue. Thanks all for the insight!! (I'll mark it as an answer if someone wants to do so)

Comment: Update: it seems to be `numpy` (or some combination of the two); I updated `pandas` to 1.2, with the same problem - but the problem then got fixed when I updated `numpy` to 1.19.4